# Can I have a semi-incognito mode for chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, private-browsing

For those of you who don't know, when you enter incognito mode, chrome uses a "temporary" cookie list. It will not read or write to the normal one. On exit of all incognito tabs, the cookies are deleted.

I want to make Chrome **read** from my normal cookies, but not **write** to them, I want it to use the temporary cookie thing for writing. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Quick Google led me to this Chrome extension: "Edit This Cookie"; maybe it is what you're looking for? I didn't dig too deeply. There is a "protect" feature to force a specific cookie read-only, and you can enable/disable the extension in Chrome to toggle it more than likely.

Comment: I don't want to make all cookies read-only, I want to make incognito mode read from my current cookies. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the read-only option, and delete your session when you close out. All cookies that are read-only should remain.

You could also use a 3rd party program like ccleaner. It will let you protect the cookies you want and then clean out what does not match the white list you've created.

The problem with the task you are seeking is it would change Chrome current functionality. That can only be done with a 3rd part extension and/or Google adding the option.

With that said, work-arounds would have to be implemented.